# Apache RewriteRule: Which one has the best performance: ^(.+) vs (.*) and ^.*$ vs .*$ ? Is there any difference?

Tags: performance, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any different between `^(.+)` and `(.*)`?

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And between `^.*$` and `.*$`?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]
```

Which one has the best Apache .htaccess performance?

Answer (score 1):

They are not even equal. The first variant requires at least one character at the beginning, and the other also matches the single slash. Sorry, I don't know enough about these regexes to make a guess about the performance, but despite the difference, they should be equal.

Comment: Thanks for try, unfortunately `RewriteRule /$ /$1 [R=301,L]` does not work.

Comment: Okey, I removed my wrong suggestion from the answer. But at least the statement about the unequality of the statements should hold.

Comment: By the way, if you meant that `RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]` does redirect from domain.com// to domain.com/, then you are wrong. It works on use some value, like domain.com/url/ redirect to domain.com/url, like does `^(.+)/$` either.